# Download Sentinel-2 bands 04 and 08 from AWS S3 of a specific area

Tags: python, amazon-s3

I am completely lost. I am trying to figure out where to start.

I need to develop a script that generates NDVI values ​​from Sentinel images provided by AWS S3.

I've already found solutions for downloading an image, etc. But I don't know how to delimit the area of ​​interest and download images from that area.

The code to calculate the NDVI and do the rest of the work is done. My difficulty is in finding the solution to download bands 08 and 04 from a particular area of ​​interest.

I'm using this code to get the images. It works.

```
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.Session().client('s3')
response = s3_client.get_object(Bucket='sentinel-s2-l1c',
                                Key='tiles/7/W/FR/2020/3/31/0/B01.jp2', 
                                RequestPayer='requester')
response_content = response['Body'].read()

with open('./B01.jp2', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(response_content)
```

I would like to know how to download two bands at the same time (bands 08 and 04) and specify an area of ​​interest.

After that I will calculate the NDVI from the images

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Are asking about finding the appropriate scene (or scenes) within an ROI and date range using the STAC API? Or, given a scene, how to subset a small section of the image and download only that?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. We use a Focused  question/Best answer model, so tutorial questions are not a good fit.  If you have in fact started, then include the code you have, for context.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question. Thank you all